# SetValue to a variable in a form Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this code in my form:

```
var code = I want to assign the codigoEmpresa value !!

{
                        xtype: 'textfield',                                                       
                        name: 'codigoEmpresa',
                        itemId: 'codigoEmpresa',
                        hidden: true,
                        hideable: false,
                    }, 
                    {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        x: 120,
                        y: 5,
                        width: 250,
                        fieldLabel: 'Empresa',
                        name: 'empresa',
                        labelWidth: 60,
                        itemId: 'comboEmpresa',
                        emptyText: 'Seleccione Empresa',
                        displayField: 'nombre',
                        valueField: 'id',
                        store: new Ext.create('SgaWeb.store.comunes.Empresas'),
                        queryMode:'local',
                        editable: false,                    
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',                                                       
                        name: 'codigoDepartamento',
                        itemId: 'codigoDepartamento',
                        hidden: true,
                        hideable: false,
                    },                        
                    {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        x: 390,
                        y: 5,
                        width: 280,
                        fieldLabel: 'Departamento',
                        labelWidth: 90,
                        name: 'departamento',
                        itemId: 'comboDepto',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        emptyText: 'Seleccione Departamento',
                        displayField: 'nombre',
                        valueField: 'id',
                        store: new Ext.create('SgaWeb.store.comunes.Departamentos'),
                        editable: false,                    
                    },
```

I need to assign the value of codigoEmpresa to a variable. How can I do this in the same form ?. I need to use that variable for others purposes in this form but I don´t know how to get the value of codigoEmpresa and set it to a variable

Comment: `var code = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="codigoEmpresa"]')[0].getValue();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var codigoEmpresaValue = this.getForm().findField('codigoEmpresa').getValue();
```

scope of the form needs to be adjusted (this, this.down(), this.up())